# python3.6 logging - fileConfig giving TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to use `logging.config.fileConfig` to initialize the logger from a `.ini` file. However I'm getting an error message when I call `fileConfig('logging_config.ini')`:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Code:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.debug('often makes a very good meal of %s', 'visiting tourists')
```

logger_config.ini:

```
[loggers]
keys=tcp_server

[handlers]
keys=stream_handler,file_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=stream_handler

[handler_stream_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[handler_file_handler]
class=FileHandler
filename="tcp_server.log"
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 148, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1012, in __init__
    filename = os.fspath(filename)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone answered (but deleted right away), your `.ini` file is wrong.  In particular the `args=(sys.stderr,)` passes `sys.stderr` as the (single) argument to `FileHandler`, when `FileHandler` requires a string containing the name of the log file.  This is described in [the documentation for using `fileConfig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format).  Please go to [the top of the same page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) to find links to tutorials and a cookbook, because `fileConfig` is generally unsafe and unsuited to a lot of use cases.

Note that fixing the `args` just gets you another error, as the `keys` setting in the `[loggers]` section is wrong: it must list at least a `root` key.  It should also list any additional keys you might use, such as something to use your `tcp_server.log`-file `FileHandler` instance.  You can then *use* that instance via `logging.getLogger` with the qualified name for the handler.

Combining all three fixes (but, again, don't do it this way):

```
diff --git a/logging_config.ini b/logging_config.ini
index 8614b9f..ee1a66b 100644
--- a/logging_config.ini
+++ b/logging_config.ini
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 [loggers]
-keys=tcp_server
+keys=root,tcp_server

 [handlers]
 keys=stream_handler,file_handler
@@ -11,6 +11,12 @@ keys=formatter
 level=DEBUG
 handlers=stream_handler

+[logger_tcp_server]
+level=DEBUG
+handlers=file_handler
+propagate=0
+qualname=whatever
+
 [handler_stream_handler]
 class=StreamHandler
 level=DEBUG
@@ -19,10 +25,9 @@ args=(sys.stderr,)

 [handler_file_handler]
 class=FileHandler
-filename="tcp_server.log"
 level=DEBUG
 formatter=formatter
-args=(sys.stderr,)
+args=("tcp_server.log",)

 [formatter_formatter]
 format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
diff --git a/tlog.py b/tlog.py
index 12a645a..bc3f07e 100644
--- a/tlog.py
+++ b/tlog.py
@@ -4,3 +4,5 @@ from logging.config import fileConfig
 fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
 logger = logging.getLogger()
 logger.debug('often makes a very good meal of %s', 'visiting tourists')
+logger = logging.getLogger('whatever')
+logger.debug('tcp thing')
```